# Div Alignment and shape

Tags: html, css

What would be the best way to align these two columns - `.responseNum & .responseText`:

Also the num column has a background -> Am I able to do this shape with CSS3 as I am unable to get the image proportions correct?

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="textMessageResponse">
    <div class="responseNum">
        <span class="number">1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="responseText">
        <p>Not bad morbi no bad luke crying twitter le me sit superhero cellphone. Strangers silent hill party problem? Loki cereal guy gentlemen monocle high school lose trolololo men true story. On freddie mercury asian le girlfriend happy facepalm blizzard bart. Charlie Sheen bacon search pokeman unsave i see what you did there vegan cookie monster humor final week.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.textMessageResponse{
    height:60px;
    background-color:#fff;
    margin:10px;
}
.textMessageResponse .responseNum .responseText{
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}

.textMessageResponse .responseNum{
    width:35px;
    height:35px;
}

.textMessageResponse .responseNum .number{
    background:url('../images/numBG.png') no-repeat;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: How do you want these columns aligned? Do you want this background to repeat, or to stretch, or to happen only once? Please be more specific with your question.

Comment: Post your css also or jsfiddle is better.

Comment: @Nightfirecat I have forgotten my CSS haha but the `.number` is like a list style and `.responseText` is the information

Comment: @Sam http://jsfiddle.net/578y5/

Answer (score 0):

Change your css like this,

```
.textMessageResponse{
    height:60px;
    background-color:#fff;
    margin:10px;
}
.textMessageResponse .responseNum, .textMessageResponse .responseText{/*change*/
    float:left;
}

.textMessageResponse .responseText{
    width:300px;/*Add this*/
}

.textMessageResponse .responseNum{
    width:35px;
    height:35px;
}

.textMessageResponse .responseNum .number{
    background:url('http://jzm.co.nz/clients/dev/_assets/images/numBG.png') no-repeat;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:block; /*change*/
}​​
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score -2):

in CSS select the display-option for the parent of your .responseNum & .responseText classes. Thus, type in css under parent class 'textMessageResponse' either:
display: inline; or display: inline-block; for horizontal alignment of your divs or
display: block; for vertical alignment of your divs.